# Should clauses always start with a relative or subordinate? Can it also start with a preposition? Can there be clauses within prepositional phrases?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, clauses, relative-clauses, questions-v-relatives

Is there a clause or a prepositional phrase in the sentence,

> *That is the large, main branch from which many smaller branches branch out*?

If it is a prepositional phrase, what is the object? If it is a clause, is it an adjective clause, because it describes a noun (the main branch) or an adverb clause, because it describes *from where* the smaller branches branch out?

Answer (score 4):

> *That is the large, main branch from which many smaller branches branch out.*

You have a lot of questions about this sentence. Let's rearrange them so the answers build on each other.

> Is there a clause or a prepositional phrase in the sentence?

There are **two** clauses **and** a preposition phrase.<sup>†</sup>

- *That is the large, main branch* is an **independent clause**: it can stand by itself as a grammatical sentence.
- *from which many smaller branches branch out* is a **dependent clause**: it cannot stand by itself but has to "hang" (that is what *depend* means) off of an independent clause. Another term for this is **subordinate clause**: it is "set in order beneath" the independent clause, just as the people who work **under** your direction are your *subordinates*.

  > is it an adjective clause ... or an adverb clause ... ?

  Let's call it an *adjectiv**al*** ('adjective-like') clause, because, yes, syntactically it "modifies" the noun phrase *the large, main branch*.<sup>‡</sup> It doesn't "modify" the verb *branch out*, because that verb is contained within it.
- *from which* is a preposition phrase acting as a constituent (sub-part) of the dependent clause.

  > If it is a prepositional phrase, what is the object?

  *From* is the preposition, *which* is its object.

  The relative clause in your example is a pretty complicated construction; it may help you if I describe how it works in some detail. It is theoretically "based on" or "derived from" an ordinary independent clause, #1 below. The term we want to modify, *the large, main branch*, is represented in this sentence by *it*; to turn the independent cause into a dependent relative clause, we start by replacing *it* with the appropriate relativizer, *which* (#2) and move that to the beginning of the clause (#3). That's a grammatical relative clause; but it leaves the preposition *from* "stranded" at the very end, and in reading that can be difficult to parse. So to make it clearer what role *which* plays in this clause we "pied-pipe" the preposition along with its object, *which*, to the front (#4).

  `1.             Many smaller branches branch out from it.`
  `2.             many smaller branches branch out from which`
  `3.      which  many smaller branches branch out from`
  `4. from which  many smaller branches branch out`

  As you see, the preposition only governs *which*, not the rest of the relative clause; this preposition phrase is syntactically only a piece of the relative clause.

Now, the questions in your title:

- > Should clauses always start with a relative or subordinate? Can it also start with a preposition?

  Dependent clauses are often introduced with a **subordinator**, which may be a **relativizer**, a preposition or a "subordinating conjunction".<sup>§</sup>

  In many cases, however, some subordinators can be omitted, like those in parentheses in the sentences below:

  > That's the man (whom) I saw.
  >   Mom says (that) I have to do my homework now.

  The rules for these omissions depend on what is being omitted in what context.

  Your term "start" is a little ambiguous. Independent clauses are never introduced with a subordinator—a subordinator marks the clause as dependent. But an independent clause may "start" with a constituent which is introduced with a subordinator; in this case, the subordinator only marks the following constituent, not the clause it is a part of.

  > [**That** this is complicated] is obvious!
- > Can there be clauses within prepositional phrases?

  Sure! A subordinate clause may act as the object of a preposition,<sup>§</sup> or a subordinate clause may "modify" the object of a preposition. In both cases the subordinate clause is inside the preposition phrase. But there is not an instance of this in your example, where the prepositional phrase is inside the subordinate clause.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Note that I say *preposition phrase*, not *preposition**al** phrase*. A terminological practise I recommend is to say *X phrase* for a phrase whose head is an X and *X**al** phrase* for a phrase which is *X-like*, which **acts like** an X. Note, too, that technically it is possible to describe the "particle" *out* as a preposition phrase, too! —but that is controversial and beyond the scope of your question.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>There are lots of fine technical distinctions to be drawn here, but again, those are really beyond the scope of your question.</sub>

<sup>§</sup> <sub>Note that some modern grammarians have reclassified most of what traditional grammar calls "subordinating conjunctions" as prepositions.</sub>

Comment: That is an impressively thorough explanation that helped this native speaker learn more about his language. Bravo.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this analogue:

> That is the small house in which I grew up.

Would you consider "in which I grew up" an *adverbial* modifier of 'house'? The house is just sitting there, being itself.

Similarly, *from which many smaller branches branch out* does not describe anything the branch is *doing*.